# Valor elemento <td> angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Cuando carga la pagina, primero aparece {{x.id}} y posteriormente carga el valor de x.id. ¿Como puedo hacer para que unicamente se muestre el valor de x.id?

Comment: Creo recordar que eso es porque se carga el contenido antes que el archivo js de angular. Quizas poniendo ese fichero en el `<head>` funcione.

Comment: @JDev ¿A que te refieres con "poniendo ese fichero en el <head>?

Comment: el link del js de angular lo puedes cargar tanto en el head como en el body. Creo redordar que si lo hacias en el body ocurria lo que te sucede y poniendolo en el head se solucionaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, incluyendo las referencias a angular js en la parte del `<head>` se soluciona.